# How to recognize the phtml file from the layout xml file?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, template, xml

I want to know the proper way of identifying a template file.
For e.g.
In my basket page (cart.phtml) there is a code like...

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping');
```

I searched for the template for this as follows.....

1. I checked "checkout.xml" file for the handle "checkout_cart_index". And find where it is written "as='shipping'" and found that code as follows...

   ```
   <block type="checkout/cart_shipping" name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/cart/shipping.phtml"/>'
   ```
2. So I checked the "checkout/cart/shipping.phtml" file and try to modify it. But nothing happend. so I confirmed that it is not the right phtml file I am looking for.
3. When I enable "Template Path Hints" from admin side , then came to know that it is coming from a different folder and it is due to the extension used. And in its layout file it is written as

   ```
   <checkout_cart_index>  
   <reference name="checkout.cart">  
   <block type="webshopapps_productmatrix/checkout_cart_shipping"name="checkout.cart.shipping" as="shipping" template="webshopapps/productmatrix/checkout/shipping.phtml"/>  
   <reference>
   </checkout_cart_index>
   ```

So My question is ,what is the proper way to know the template files which is used in our page as ChildHtml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you sort of answered your question by yourself : If you are really lost, and can't find which template is called, then the best way is to use the **Template Path Hints**.

But I agree that it is sometimes a pain to use, as it is breaking the design, make you have to go to the settings, reload the page, etc...

So when I look for which template to modify, I usually start by making a search in my layout files. If your code is like that `echo $this->getChildHtml('shipping');`, then, you know that you need to find a block called `shipping`.

You also need to know how the configuration files for layout are loaded. The order of preference will be

**Current theme / Current package > Default theme / Current package > Default theme / Default package**

And last thing, if a module depends of another module, then it will be loaded after, and therefore will replace its configuration. (Like in your case)

Sometimes it can be a detective work, but most of the time, just by searching for the right name in the different layout folders you will have no more than 3 or 4 files, and you should be able to get the good one.

Comment: Hello. By looking which file  I know that  a module depends of another module.

Comment: Those declarations are in the etc/modules/ folder, in each module declaration file. You should have a line stating <depends><Module/></depends>. If there is no dependence, then this line will be absent.

Comment: @kishore-patra If this way of doing things correspond to what you are looking for, please consider accepting the answer.